# Injecting Helper causes "Undefined constant" and "'generated' directory permission is read-only"

Tags: magento2.3, helper, dependency-injection

When I inject the helper class it gives me the below errors.
If I remove the reference to the Helper class in the constructor then everything works perfectly.

```
controller file: /var/www/html/app/code/[Company]/[Module]/Controller/login/Index.php
<?php
namespace [Company]\[Module]\Controller\login;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  protected $_pageFactory;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    ...,
    //removing the below line removes the error
    \[Company]\[Module]\Helper\[Module] $helper
  )
  {
    ...
    //removing the below line removes the error
    $this->_helper = $helper;
    return parent::__construct($context);
  }




helper file: /var/www/html/app/code/[Company]/[Module]/Helper/[Module].php
<?php
namespace \[Company]\[Module]\Helper;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class [Module] extends AbstractHelper
{
}


PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant '[Company]\[Module]\Helper' in /var/www/html/app/code/[Company]/[Module]/Helper/[Module].php:2
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/var/www/html/v...')
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('[Company]\\[Module]...')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('[Company]\\[Module]...')
#4 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(125): class_exists('\\[Company]\\[Modu...')

...

main.CRITICAL: Class [Company]\[Module]\Helper\[Module] does not exist
Class [Company]\[Module]\Controller\login\Index\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only. [] []
main.ERROR: Class [Company]\[Module]\Helper\[Module] does not exist
Class [Company]\[Module]\Controller\login\Index\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only. [] []
$ ls -ld /var/www/html/generated/code/[Company]/[Module]/Controller/login/Index/
drwxrwsr-x 2 apache apache 6 Nov  4 16:08 /var/www/html/generated/code/[Company]/[Module]/Controller/login/Index/
```

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing any obvious problems with code

Have you given Magento the recommended permissions.  This will solve the ./generated permissions error

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/trouble/readiness/tshoot_rc_perms.html#one-user-resolution

```
cd /var/www/html && find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+w {} + && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: yes `cd /var/www/html;chown -R magento:apache .;chmod -R ug+rwX,o-rwx .;chmod g+s var pub/static pub/media generated app/etc;chmod -R a+rwX generated;chmod u+x bin/magento`

Comment: f.y.i. `chmod -R` is safer, more efficient, and easier to read than `find [...] -exec chmod [...] +`